# how to concat data and make dynamic query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetMyEvent_SP`(in employeeId varchar(45),
in eventType int,

in searchTermtext text,
in skillIdArray text,
in startDate varchar(50),
in endDate varchar(50),
in offsetvalue int,

in recordlimit int,
out total int
 )
BEGIN

declare totalcount int default 0;
          SET @Whereclause='where  1=1 and isMyEvent=1';
          SET @empID = concat('"',employeeId,'"');
          SET @SearchTerm=concat('"%',searchTermtext,'%"');
          SET @startdate=concat('"',startDate,'"');
          SET @enddate=concat('"',endDate,'"');
          SET @currentdate=concat('"',curdate(),'"');

          SET @skillid=concat('"',skillIdArray,'"');


    if(skillIdArray is not null and skillIdArray <> '') then

      set @Whereclause=CONCAT(@Whereclause," and FIND_IN_SET(skills,",@skillid,")" );
    end if;

   if(eventType is not null and eventType=0 and eventType<>-1 ) then
     set @Whereclause=CONCAT(@Whereclause," and date(scheduledDate)<",@currentdate );
      end if;

      if(eventType is not null and eventType=1) then
            set @Whereclause=CONCAT(@Whereclause," and  date(scheduledDate)>",@currentdate);
       end if;

       if(searchTermtext is not null and  searchTermtext<>'') then

    set @Whereclause=CONCAT(@Whereclause," and  searchTerm like ",@SearchTerm );
    end if;


  if(startDate is not null and endDate is not null and startDate<>'1111/11/11' and endDate<>'1111/11/11'  ) then
       set @Whereclause=CONCAT(@Whereclause," and (date(scheduledDate) between ",@startdate," and ",@enddate,")" );
     end if;


set @SQLQuery  =CONCAT("select eventId,scheduleId,description,events,eventType,
scheduledDate,name,designation,image,skills,duration,status,attachmentPath,
attendingStatus,meetingRoom,hasRequested from EventList_View ", @Whereclause);

 set @CountSQLQuery=concat("select count(*) from EventList_View ", @Whereclause," into ",total);



 if(offsetvalue<recordlimit) then
    set @QueryfforPagination=CONCAT(@SQLQuery," limit ",recordlimit );
     PREPARE querystatement FROM @QueryfforPagination;
   EXECUTE querystatement;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE querystatement;

    else
     set  @QueryfforPagination=CONCAT(@SQLQuery," limit ",recordlimit," offset ",offsetvalue);

       PREPARE querystatement FROM @QueryfforPagination;
   EXECUTE querystatement;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE querystatement;

    end if;

   select @CountSQLQuery;


END
```

this is my query i am able to get data  i have to calculate total record count for that i have make one query

```
set @CountSQLQuery=concat("select count(*) from EventList_View ", @Whereclause," into ",total);
```

but when i try to concat in @CountSQLQuery it always give null its not concat please tell me where am doing wrong why @CountSQLQuery not concat so that i can get data please suggest me.

Comment: `total` is probably `null` which would cause the whole string to be null unless you wrap it with a `IFNULL(total,'')`

Comment: Also, your WHERE could just be `where  isMyEvent=1` instead of `where  1=1 and isMyEvent=1`

Comment: problem is coming to set value to Output parameter @KayNelson please help me in this i have to set count in output parameter

Comment: 1- When you are checking `eventType=0` then there is no point to check  `and eventType<>-1` 2- you are concating `courdate()` as a string, it's wrong, just use `concat(x, curdate());` 3- if you are passing your date parameters in this format `yyyy/mm/dd` it's wrong, mysql date format is `yyyy-mm-dd` so please fix these issues and see what happens next